# What is the thing?

Tags: riddle

> If we cut the thing becomes one,
>
> If we don't cut the thing becomes two,

**What is the thing?**

Comment: Is this supposed to have an "it" between the "thing"s and "becomes"? ("If we cut the thing it becomes one") That would make it grammatically correct.

Comment: @Riker It could also be made grammatically correct by putting a comma after "cut" both times. Trouble is, that gives it quite a different meaning than the change you suggested...

Comment: Can user point us in a direction. There are so many answers that fit. We are just hitting darts in the dark.

Answer (score 25):

I think a straightforward answer may be

> Scissors.

Explanation:

> When cutting with the scissors, the two blades go together to form one, when not cutting the blades are two separate entities.

Comment: I knew someone else would say this :)

Comment: I don’t like this because if you don’t cut, it doesn’t become two, it already  is two.

Answer (score 22):

The thing could be(Bit of a stretch)

> A computer file

Explanation:

> If we cut it, it becomes 1
>  But if we don't cut it (copy it), It becomes 2.

Comment: If we cut it, it *remains* 1

Answer (score 21):

I don't think this is the correct answer, but just a try.

> Roman numeral Two (II)
>  If you cut the Roman numeral 2 in vertical, it will become two ones. If you don't cut it, it will remain as two.

Another answer can be

> **The word count** of "One thing". If you cut the thing from it, it becomes 1(**One**) and if you don't cut the thing, it becomes two(**One** and **thing**)

Answer (score 16):

This also makes sense

> It is the number **2**.

Explanation:

> if we don't cut (half) it remains **2**. and if we cut (half) it, it will become **1**.

Answer (score 9):

> The head of a revolutionary who belongs to an organization on the verge of schism.

Explanation:

> If you cut their head off, the revolutionary becomes a martyr, and unites the fractious organization. If you don't, the schism widens, and the organization splits in two.

Answer (score 5):

M pretty sure not the intended answer but got in mind so posting it. It could be:

> [image]

Explanation:

> When director says Cut he/she joins it and it becomes one. If not cut then its not joined(not completely separate though)

Comment: To my knowledge, the [clapperboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard) is used at the beginning of scenes, and has no relation to the "cutting" of the action at the end.

Answer (score 3):

There's

> always wedding cakes and this weird German wedding tradition of sawing a log.  If the cutting takes place on the wedding day then the two individuals have probably "become one" but if it doesn't then it may indicate a falling out or someone getting stood up (and becoming two / breaking up).

Answer (score 2):

The thing may be

> Ties
>
>  If one cuts ties, it becomes one, the one who cut ties, in the sense a split relationship;
>  If one doesn't cut ties, it "becomes" two, both of whom refuse to sever a relationship, in the sense of "suits them both."
>
>  I think most answers so far "remain one" or "remain two" and I'm so far stumped as to how else anything cut can *become* one or *become* two in a literal sense, as in starting from some other number. Though quite possibly in a medical sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is my first time answering on this site so hopefully i got the syntax for the spoilers right, but i believe the answer is ...

> A Corner

because ...

> by not cutting you are still left with the 1 corner, however if you cut corners you'll end up with 2 spots where you had to change your path. which would be 2 corners.

Answer (score 1):

"If we cut the thing" becomes one...

> ... one hypothetical clause.

"If we don't cut the thing" becomes two...

> ... meaning a second hypothetical clause.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be

> Half time

Explanation

> If you cut the half time out of a soccer/football (depending on your origin) game for example the game becomes one long game, if you don't the game is split in two halves. Although this seems a bit stretched since two halves are still part of a whole.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> Hair

My explanation

> Before hair is cut, the ends are split, when the hair is cut, the end
>  is singular?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stretch, but how about

> A Room

Explanation

> If you have two adjacent rooms and you cut (the wall/ceiling/floor) of one, you now have one room, but if you don't cut it you have two rooms.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's...

> The word count, in the verb phrase.

So that...

> In the phrase "Cut," There is only one (1) word. However, in the phrase "Don't cut," there are two (2).

Answer (score 1):

My take on this :

> It is an area enclosed by a circle.
>  When the circle is not cut, there are **TWO** areas : inside the circle and outside the circle.
>  When the circle is cut, both areas merge to become **ONE**.
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> Movie Film

Explanation

> Prior to digital editing, to do a cut in film meant physically cutting the film and joining the two pieces together.  If we do a cut, two pieces become one. If we do not cut, the two pieces of film remain separate.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Marriage. Because if two people are joined in marriage, they can be counted as one entity- but if they get cut ties (get a divorce) then they're two again.

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58451/43636

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... it is...

> Salary
>
>  If you, as my manager, cut my salary; then my income becomes one (e.g. dollar per minute).
>  If you don't cut it, my income will become two.